# Spring boot Integration Tests. Separate Abstract Kafka tests from rest tests

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, integration-testing

I have AbstractTest class which is contains @SpringBootTest, @EmbeddedKafka, all kafka and rest required fields and methods. I want to separate this two logics by developing AbstractKafkaTest and AbstractRestTest classes for avoiding unnecessary kafka startup. After running this all test the application context failing to startup, because of the ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers} couldn't find. This is my application-test.yml

```
`spring:
  application:
    # Application name.
    name:          kafka_rest_application
  # In memory database
  datasource:
    platform: h2
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS custom_schema
    username: sa
    password: sa
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false
    show-sql: true
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: custom_schema
        format_sql: true
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults : false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop

  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${spring.embedded.kafka.brokers}
    response-timeout: 60
    listener:
      ack-mode: manual_immediate
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      properties:
        "spring.json.add.type.headers": false
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      poll-interval-ms: 300

# Kafka Configurations
kafka:
  topic-topic-01:
    name: topic-01
    consumer:
      autoStart: true
      clientId: clientId-01
      groupId: groupId-01
      containerId: se01
  topic-topic-02:
    name: topic-02
    consumer:
      autoStart: true
      clientId: clientId-02
      groupId: groupId-02
      containerId: se02
  topic-topic-03:
    name: topic-03
    consumer:
      autoStart: true
      clientId: clientId-03
      groupId: groupId-03
      containerId: se03
  topic-topic-04:
    name: topic-04
    consumer:
      autoStart: true
      clientId: clientId-04
      groupId: groupId-04
      containerId: se04
  topic-topic-05:
    name: topic-05
    consumer:
      autoStart: true
      clientId: clientId-05
      groupId: groupId-05
      containerId: se05`
```

Some solution for making separate abstract test classes.